# NPM Install Latest Beta Version of a Specific Major

Tags: npm, npm-install

Let's say I'm installing from an NPM repo with the following version packages:

```
...
2.5.0-beta.1
2.5.0
2.6.0-beta.1
2.6.0-beta.2
3.0.0
3.1.0-beta.1
...
```

What do I need to have in my package.json so that the latest beta version of Major 2 is installed. In the above example, I'd want to install `2.6.0-beta.2`. I don't want to go to major 3.

I've tried using `^2` and `<3` or `<3.0.0`, but they all result in getting `2.5.0`. Obviously, if I use `@beta` I get the latest beta of major 3 (`3.1.0-beta.1`), which isn't what I want.
I also can't just have `2.6.0-beta.2` because betas are still going to be released, I don't want to have to manually update it everytime that happens.

We need to get the beta version of the package (which we own) to validate it, but only on major 2 right now.

Answer (score 1):

```json
{
   "dependencies": {
     "your-package": ">=2.6.0-beta.2 < 2.6.1"
   }
}
```

This will only install versions 2.6.0-beta.2 -> 2.6.0-beta.[infinity]

Here is a useful tool:

- Check against actual public npm modules: https://semver.npmjs.com/

You can also use semver npm package.

[image: semver from command line]

For others reading this answer, it's good to have some knowledge about semver (the system for node module version numbers).  The parts of a version number are:

`[major]`.`[minor]`.`[patch]`-`[preid]`.`[prerelease]`

Here is an example of a complex version number "1.2.3-beta.4"

- "1" is the major version.
- "2" is the minor version.
- "3" is the patch version.
- "beta" is the prerelease tag (aka "preid").
- "4" is the prerelease version.

Npm's documentation says...

> If a version has a prerelease tag (for example, 1.2.3-alpha.3) then it
> will only be allowed to satisfy comparator sets if at least one
> comparator with the same [major, minor, patch] tuple also has a
> prerelease tag.
>
> --- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#prerelease-tags

In human terms that means that if you include a prerelease tag, then npm will only consider versions in your specified range that have the same `major`.`minor`,`patch`-`preid`.

For example, this constraint `"^1.0.0-beta.0"` will match the following: `1.0.0-beta.23` and `1.2.0` but it would not match `1.0.0-alpha.100` even though the prerelease version "100" is technically greater than "0" because alpha does not match beta.

In your case, the constraint `"^2.6.0-beta.2"` would also match "3.0.0" but not "3.1.0-beta.1" because even though it has "beta" as the pre id, when dealing with preid tags, the tupples must match. The 3.1.0 tuple doesn't match the 2.6.0 tuple, so no match.  Still, you said don't want version "3.0.0" to match. You only wanted the 2.6.0 prereleases.

Therefore, we must make our range more restrictive.

`">=2.6.0-beta.2 < 2.6.1"`

`>=2.6.0-beta.2` means that we want a version greater than or equal to `2.6.0-beta.2`.  Any version that matches 2.6.0-beta.X will match. But also so will 3.0.0 or even 4.0.0.  We need an upper bound.

`< 2.6.1` means that the version number MUST to be less than 2.6.1

So that only leaves us with versions between 2.6.0-beta.2 and 2.6.1

The only version numbers that satisfy that range are versions that start with 2.6.0 and have a beta tag.

Comment: `>=2.6.0-beta.2 < 2.6.1` that would only get the latest beta of that major AND minor AND patch. I need to get the latest beta of the major; if I have to specify the minor and patch then there' not much of a point. Thanks, but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, to be clear, beta versions ARE specific to the major, minor, and patch.   A beta of 1.0.0-beta.1 and another of 2.3.4-beta.4 have no relationship.  Meaning, one is not larger than the other, or smaller. They have no possible connection and cannot be compared. They are apples and oranges.  Prereleases of alpha, beta, and rc are specific to the major minor patch tuple.

If you want the latest beta of a major version number you can do `>=3.0.0-beta.0 < 3.0.1` but you have to know the major version number ahead of time.